# unable to read kafka topic data using spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-kafka, streaming

I have data like below in one of the topics which I created named `"sampleTopic"`

```
sid,Believer
```

Where the first argument is the `username` and the second argument is the `song name` which the user frequently listens. Now, I have started `zookeeper`, `Kafka server`, and `producer` with the topic name as mentioned above. I have entered the above data for that topic using `CMD`. Now, I want to read the topic in spark perform some aggregation, and write it back to stream. Below is my code:

```
package com.sparkKafka
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object SparkKafkaTopic {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkKafka").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    println("hey")
    val df = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "sampleTopic1")
      .load()
    val query = df.writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .start().awaitTermination()


  }
}
```

However, when I execute the above code it gives :

```
    +----+--------------------+------------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
| key|               value|       topic|partition|offset|           timestamp|timestampType|
+----+--------------------+------------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
|null|[73 69 64 64 68 6...|sampleTopic1|        0|     4|2020-05-31 12:12:...|            0|
+----+--------------------+------------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
```

with infinite below looping messages too

```
20/05/31 11:56:12 INFO Fetcher: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-0d6807b9-fcc9-4847-abeb-f0b81ab25187--264582860-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition sampleTopic1-0 to offset 4.
20/05/31 11:56:12 INFO Fetcher: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-0d6807b9-fcc9-4847-abeb-f0b81ab25187--264582860-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition sampleTopic1-0 to offset 4.
20/05/31 11:56:12 INFO Fetcher: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-0d6807b9-fcc9-4847-abeb-f0b81ab25187--264582860-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition sampleTopic1-0 to offset 4.
20/05/31 11:56:12 INFO Fetcher: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-0d6807b9-fcc9-4847-abeb-f0b81ab25187--264582860-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition sampleTopic1-0 to offset 4.
20/05/31 11:56:12 INFO Fetcher: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-0d6807b9-fcc9-4847-abeb-f0b81ab25187--264582860-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition sampleTopic1-0 to offset 4.
20/05/31 11:56:12 INFO Fetcher: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-0d6807b9-fcc9-4847-abeb-f0b81ab25187--264582860-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition sampleTopic1-0 to offset 4.
```

I need output something like below:
[image]

As modified on the suggestion by Srinivas I got the following output:
[image]

Not sure what exactly is wrong over here. Please guide me through it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The suggested dependencies worked for me but I am facing a new problem over here. please go through the question

Comment: can you add schema of your data in kafka ??

Comment: How to do that? Actually I am new to this integration thing. The schema will be the string for both the columns. I have modified my output

Comment: or can you post your kafka message ??

Comment: which message? you are asking for the data that is getting published in the topic?

Comment: yes, that message

Comment: I have updated code below & change your code & post message here ??

Comment: my data will be published like this `sid,Thunder` where first param is `userName` and second param is `songName` and I need output as shown in the expected output image so that I can perform count aggregation and write it back to a new topic

Comment: ok, can check below code in my answer & try again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `spark-sql-kafka` library to your build file. Check below.

**build.sbt**

```scala
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.3.0"  
// Change to Your spark version
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>    // Change to Your spark version
</dependency>
```

Change your code like below

```scala
    package com.sparkKafka
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    case class KafkaMessage(key: String, value: String, topic: String, partition: Int, offset: Long, timestamp: String)

    object SparkKafkaTopic {

      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        //val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkKafka").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
        println("hey")
        val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkKafka").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
        import spark.implicits._
        val mySchema = StructType(Array(
          StructField("userName", StringType),
          StructField("songName", StringType)))
        val df = spark
          .readStream
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
          .option("subscribe", "sampleTopic1")
          .load()

        val query = df
          .as[KafkaMessage]
          .select(split($"value", ",")(0).as("userName"),split($"value", ",")(1).as("songName"))
          .writeStream
          .outputMode("append")
          .format("console")
          .start()
          .awaitTermination()
      }
    }

     /*
        +------+--------+
        |userid|songname|
        +------+--------+
        |   sid|Believer|
        +------+--------+
       */

      }
    }
```

Comment: Added a new comment and modified the question according to the new problem faced. please help me with that.

Comment: When I merged your code, it gives an error saying that an `unable to find  encoder for type  [KafkaMessage]`

Comment: it gives below error `def as[U](implicit evidence$2: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]

:: Experimental :: Returns a new Dataset where each record has been mapped on to the specified type. The method used to map columns depend on the type of U:
◾When U is a class, fields for the class will be mapped to columns of the same name(case sensitivity is determined by spark.sql.caseSensitive).
` on the [kafkamessage] line

Comment: Yeah. It worked but unable to add schema for the messages. as well as how do I add some window for the arriving input messages? check my edited question output

Comment: I have modified the question with the output I got

Comment: I created the schema and tried to add it as an option while subscribing to the Kafka topic but it didn't work. Returns the same output format

Comment: I modified your code and it worked for me. Data is of CSV format so we don't need to add json support. The formatting problem is resolved but how do I add the windowing for my problem ? Please see  your modified code and suggest me

Comment: Please upvote if above solution helps .. for window operations may be you can check this doc - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time,

Comment: since i am also new to window operations .. giving you above docs link for your reference

Comment: Thanks @Srinivas. Also, I have one doubt if I follow your code, how can I apply group by on this dataframe. Could you please give me some suggestions or links to follow? I am a newbie so struggling a lot with Kafka

Comment: above like has groupby operation example check once may be that will help you

Answer (score 1):

spark-sql-kafka jar is missing, which is having the implementation of 'kafka' datasource.

you can add the jar using config option or build fat jar which includes spark-sql-kafka jar. Please use relevant version of jar

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("SparkKafka").master("local[*]")
  .config("spark.jars","/path/to/spark-sql-kafka-xxxxxx.jar")
  .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Added a new comment and modified the question according to the new problem faced. please help me with that.